# Force URL rewrite on payment tunnel Prestashop

Tags: url, url-rewriting, payment, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to force the URL rewrite for the basic payment module steps in Prestashop 1.6

What I did do so far is obtaining this result :

```
1/http://www.domainname.com/summary
2/summary&step=1
3/summary&step=2
etc.
```

What I want to have is this result :

```
1/http://www.domainname.com/summary
2/shippingaddress
3/paymentmethod
```

etc.

I made changes in the backend (SEO / URL) and in the controller of Prestashop.

Is it doable ? Can you advise ?

Thanks!